# Converse nonimplication using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, boolean-logic

How to do a [converse nonimplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_nonimplication) using VB.NET (between two integers)?

I have two Flag Enumerations `myFlag1` and `myFlag2` and want to obtain `myFlag3` containing just values that are in `myFlag2` but not also in `myFlag1`.
I know `XOR` operator but this is not good.

[image: The Venn Diagram of "It is not the case that B implies A" (the red area is true)]

Say I have

```
010110
100011
------
100001 (this is what I need)
```

Also

```
111
101
---
000
```

Comment: What have you tried?  The truth table on the page you linked is straightforward enough...

Comment: The article you linked to is all about _boolean_ logic. Can you explain how this is supposed to transfer to integers?

Comment: I have two Flag Enumerations. And want to obtain converse nonimplication. I know XOR operator but this is not good.

Comment: You should post an example with expected output, plus an short explanation of how you arrived at output on paper.  Then it would be much easier to provide you the VB.net syntax (and also feel less like we're simply giving you the answer to question X on your homework worksheet).

Comment: You mention that you know of XOR but that it isn't good. Is there a restriction on using it in your homework?

Comment: no, I have any restriction, I can use XOR, but this is not enough.

Comment: Do you want to do this bitwise between the integers or do you want to convert the integers to boolean values first?

Comment: Give an example of your flag enumerations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim a As Integer = 22
Dim b As Integer = 35

Dim output As Integer = (b And Not a)
```

It's almost exactly how you would say it out loud when trying to explain it to someone. :)

Comment: The numbers I used initially were not dependent on your example.  I have updated my answer.  The result would be 33 (or 10001), do a test.

Comment: @MikeC - The numbers in the example are 22 and 35 :)  That being said, your code is still correct.

Comment: @pstrjds - Sorry I have reversed my "endianness", I'll fix it :).  But like you said, either way it still works.

Comment: @MikeC - No worries, you still gained my upvote...my first answer was (a & b) ^ b, your answer is cleaner. Also I totally cheated on the binary conversion and used the windows calculator since I figured the endianness would match VB.

Comment: @serhio What are you talking about?  This code works for your second example as well.  I used `7` and `5` as a test.  The result is 0.